# Script sets color to multiple objects from empty GameObject instead of a color to a child/children and isnt random

Tags: javascript, c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I have made a c# script that sets a color to my objects (in this case tiles). The problem is it sets a color to multiple objects instead of only one object. Does anyone have a solution? People with knowledge of javascript can also answer.

**EDIT**: I updated my code a little bit. I want to make thing more clear.
I have 16 Objects (tile) that are children of one empty gameobject (tiles). 
Every 1.5 sec (for example) I want only one tile to change color, randomly.

**EDIT** I updated my question and posted the solution/script in an answer below.

```
private float timer = 0.0f;

Color red = Color.red;
Color blue = Color.blue;
Color green = Color.green;
Color white = Color.white;

public Transform tiles;

void Update () 
{       
    timer += Time.deltaTime;

    if (timer >= 1.5f)//change the float value here to change how long it takes to switch.
    {

        Transform tile = tiles.GetChild (Random.Range (0, 16));

        int rand = Random.Range (1, 4);


            if (rand == 1) {
                tile.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color = red;
            } else if (rand == 2) {
                tile.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color = blue;
            } else {
                tile.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color = green;
            }
        timer = 0;
    }
}
```

[image: after the first 1.5 sec all these tiles are colored]

Comment: And in case you're not sure how to do that, the easiest way to start doing that in Unity is to pepper your code with `Debug.Log()` calls, and figure out if your code isn't executing quite how you think it is.

Comment: I know how to debug, but I don't know what i should log into my console.
I tried `Debug.Log(tile)` and `Debug.Log(tiles)` wich give me both the output "Object".

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [Unity Scripting API for Random.Range](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html).

Particularly the part for 'integer' that reads: Note that `max` is exclusive, so using `Random.Range( 0, 10 )` will **return values between 0 and 9**.

Update your code to be

```
int rand = Random.Range(1, 4);
```

On another note, the [Unity Scripting API for the Color Constructor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color-ctor.html) specifies that colors are created using `Floats` that clamp values to between `0.0f` and `1.0f`. So you can rewrite your declarations:

```
Color red   = new Color(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
Color green = new Color(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
Color blue  = new Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
Color white = new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
```

Or use the [existing static variables](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html):

```
Color red   = Color.red;
Color green = Color.green;
Color blue  = Color.blue;
Color white = Color.white;
```

Comment: Right, and the `float` version of Random.Range, max is inclusive, but not so for the `int` version. I think it's so things like 'Array.Length' can be used in the max place which produces size one larger than the last index of the array.

Comment: Thanks for the usefull information. The real question still remains.
How can i give a color to one single tile

Comment: You only want one random object of the 16 to change every 1.5 seconds over and over again?

Comment: Yes. 16 Objects are children of one empty GameObject called "tiles".
And i want to change 1 of them every x seconds

Comment: If I understand you correctly, which I probably don't, you could move the `Transform tile = tiles.GetChild (Random.Range (0, 16));`  to the `void Start() {}` function.

Comment: If statement won't work anymore
Because `tile.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color` is undefined

Comment: Then put a declaration `Transform tile;` above the `Start()` and `Update()` function, but keep `tile = tiles.GetChild(Random.Range (0, 16));` in the `Start()` function but without the `Transform` declaration.

Comment: I tried this and it works. It now only sets color to one tile. Now im gonna try implementing a function that sets it to a random tile because the Random.Range() selects the same number over and over again. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Okay so finally i have the solution. I'm going to post it here in case someone in the future needs it.

So in short, the script gives a random tile a color (red, green or blue) every 1.5 seconds. **Every tile is a child** of my **EmptyGameObject called tiles**. It's chosen randomly. The tile is given a tag too because it's part of my game.

```
//PUBLIC VARIABLES
public Transform tiles;

//PRIVATE VARIABLES
private Transform tile;
private float timer = 0.0f;

//COLORS
Color red = Color.red;
Color blue = Color.blue;
Color green = Color.green;

void Start(){       
    tile = tiles.GetChild (Random.Range (0, 16));
    }

void Update () 
{       
    GOsWithTag = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Colored Tile");
    timer += Time.deltaTime;

    if (timer >= 1.5f)//change the float value here to change how long it takes to switch.
    {
        SetRandom ();
        int rand = Random.Range (1, 4);


        if (rand == 1) {
            tile.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color = red;
            this.tile.gameObject.tag = "Colored Tile";
        } else if (rand == 2) {
            tile.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color = blue;
            this.tile.gameObject.tag = "Colored Tile";              
        } else {
            tile.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color = green;
            this.tile.gameObject.tag = "Colored Tile";
        }

        timer = 0;
    }// CLOSING FIRST IF STATEMENT

    GameOver ();

} //CLOSING Update()

void SetRandom(){
    for (float r = 0.0f; r < 9999; r += 1.5f * Time.deltaTime){
        int nRand = Random.Range(0, 16);
        tile = tiles.GetChild (nRand);
    }           
}
```